# UsersController's actionUploadUserPhoto and actionCropUserPhoto with Element API

Tags: plugin-elementapi, upload

Can you use the [Element API](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ElementAPI) plugin to utilize [UsersController's](https://craftcms.com/classreference/controllers/UsersController) [actionUploadUserPhoto](https://craftcms.com/classreference/controllers/UsersController#actionUploadUserPhoto-detail) and [actionCropUserPhoto](https://craftcms.com/classreference/controllers/UsersController#actionCropUserPhoto-detail) methods?

Answer (score 1):

Not natively.  The Element API plugin provides a "read only" API to Craft's controller endpoints.  Both `actionUploadUserPhoto` and `actionCropUserPhoto` request POST/write requests.

You could fork it and add POST/write functionality to the plugin/API, though.